# How can I have Internet Explorer 7 and 8 installed on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Multiple versions of Internet Explorer on a machine](https://superuser.com/questions/17670/multiple-versions-of-internet-explorer-on-a-machine)

I'm a developer, and I need to test my web applications on Internet Explorer 7 and 8. How can I have them both installed on Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the IE8 Developer Tools (under Tools menu, or press F12). You can set the Browser mode and Document mode to IE7.

I've used this for development, and it has worked well.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - you can't

Long Answer - Install [Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) and run IE7 in that.

EDIT: I have not suggested any other VM solutions as they will require an extra Windows XP licence - Windows 7 Pro, Ultimate and Enterprise include a Windows XP licence to be used in Windows XP Mode

Comment: Or any other Virtual PC.

Comment: @Martin: I deliberately did not include that info as it will require an extra licence for Windows inside any other VM. The Windows 7 licence (Pro, Ultimate or Enterprise) includes a licence for Windows XP in XP Mode.

Comment: Okay, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

IE8 does have compatibility mode that can render pages as IE7 would see them. I would not relay on this for testing Javascript but for testing CSS it is fine.

Comment: I've seen plenty of pages that look correct in IE7 but don't render or function correctly under IE8 compatibility mode.

Comment: Compatibility mode is not full IE7 browser mode. F12 will give you the developer's tools where you can set the Browser and Documents Modes to both IE7. Compatibility mode will merely give you IE7 Document mode and IE8 Compat View Browser mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try something like this site:

http://spoon.net/browsers/

which allows you to download and run various browsers in "sandboxed" modes, that can run alongside each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)