# Good IE6, IE7 simulator applications?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple versions of internet explorer on a machine](https://superuser.com/questions/17670/multiple-versions-of-internet-explorer-on-a-machine)

I have IE8 installed, I would like to test websites in IE6 and IE7. I cannot use Adobe's BrowserLab to test because the website needing tests contains dynamic content.

I cannot find a good application to simulate IE6 or 7.

Is one available/recommended? Or can I install and run IE6 through 8 on my machine at the same time?

Comment: Scout (http://saucelabs.com/scouthome) looks like what I've needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled some more based on the responses I received. I found that IETester works the best for my needs http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

I had issues with the other simulators I installed and tried :(. SuperPreview does not log into websites and Microsoft's VM downloads would not run on my machine. Internet Explorer collection would not run either (IE 1.5 worked for some reason, but IE6 did not).

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft makes VM's available with pre-installed Windows & IE6 or IE7, etc. available.

You can find them at [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en).

Comment: But Microsoft's VMs require you to redownload them like very month and take much more space than you'd need to just run IE.

Comment: the space required for a Windows XP image is an issue nowadays?

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/04/internet-explorer-for-mac-ie7-ie8-ie-9-free/ looks good, too.

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft's [SuperPreview](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2020) (free download):

> Expression Web SuperPreview shows your web pages rendered in all versions of Internet Explorer [and some other browsers]. You can view the pages side by side or as an onion-skin overlay and use rulers, guides and zoom/pan tools to precisely identify differences in layout. You can even compare your page comp to how the targeted browsers render the page.
>   ...
>   After the [60 day] trial period, SuperPreview continues to render your pages in all versions of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Or [Internet Explorer Collection](http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm).

NOTE: IE6 can be a bit buggy on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

one app i use to test not only for ie-splat but also for other systems is [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/).

Answer (score 0):

http://spoon.net/browsers/ is another good one. It lets you run the most recent 2 or 3 versions of IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera, all sandboxed so that they don't interfere with your "real" installed browser.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to get to to work on my machine with IE 8.