# Free Windows Application to test websites in IE 6/7/8

Tags: windows-7, windows, browser, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple versions of internet explorer on a machine](https://superuser.com/questions/17670/multiple-versions-of-internet-explorer-on-a-machine)

is there any app like this out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the extent with which you want to test.  If you just want to see what the site *looks like*, but aren't necessarily concerned with how it functions, you can use a service like [browsershots.com](http://browsershots.org/).

> Browsershots makes screenshots of your
>   web design in different operating
>   systems and browsers. It is a free
>   open-source online web application
>   providing developers a convenient way
>   to test their website's browser
>   compatibility in one place. When you
>   submit your web address, it will be
>   added to the job queue. A number of
>   distributed computers will open your
>   website in their browser. Then they
>   will make screenshots and upload them
>   to our central dedicated servers for
>   your review.

If you want a browser based solution that doesn't require a large install, you can use [spoon.net](http://spoon.net/).

> Run your apps anywhere. Spoon
>   virtualization lets you run desktop
>   apps with no installs – at work, at
>   home, or on the road.

There is also Microsoft's [Expression Web SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx).

> We built SuperPreview to simplify the
>   process of testing and debugging
>   layout issues across different web
>   browsers and platforms. You can view
>   your pages in multiple browsers
>   simultaneously or view how a page
>   renders in a browser and compare it to
>   a comp or mock-up image of a page.

However, for the best compatibility testing, what you really need is the **real** Internet Explorer running on a **real** Windows OS.  Fortunately, you don't need three computers to do this with the concept of *virtual machines*.

You have two different ways to use virtual machines.  You can install [Microsoft's Virtual PC 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6&displaylang=en) and download the **free** [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility Virtual PC Images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) that come preloaded with the following OS/Browser configurations (depending on what you download):

Windows XP with IE 6
Windows XP with IE 7
Windows XP with IE 8
Windows Vista with IE 7
Windows Vista with IE 8

These virtual images expire every 90 days, at which point you have to re-download them and load them as new virtual machines.

If you are running Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate, the absolute best setup (in my opinion) is to use [Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) and [differencing disks to load up multiple virtual machines with each browser, side by side](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2009/06/24/using-windows-7s-xp-mode-to-run-ie-6-and-ie-7-side-by-side/).

It is also worth mentioning that you don't have to use Microsoft's Virtual PC 2007 software to emulate a machine.  There is also [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/), which can both be used to load in the VirtualPC hard disk images mentioned previously.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the fact that this current set is due to expire in a few hours, have you considered using [VirtualPC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) with the [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VHDs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef)?

There is no website that will allow you to test so thoroughly and it is a lot less hassle doing this than you might think.

Comment: what? over 7 GB for IE testing? :)

Comment: @Alexadra: Well, yes, if you want to test all versions of IE on both XP and Vista, if you want to be really thorough in your testing.#

Comment: ...they are complete virtualised machines.  The XP files are single files, and the two Vista VMs are three or four files.  It's the best way to test, as they are in effect, full standard operating systems.  And they are free!

Comment: well i only have like 10G space :)

Comment: BTW, the Vista VMs will not expire until 90 days after you install them, you need one of the XP VMs to test IE6 as well.

Comment: If you only have a little disk space left, I'd suggest just installing one VM at a time, and then deleting after testing. However, it would be a lot more convenient to get an external drive and move all your files onto that to free up some space.

Comment: tx. i`m trying ie6 on winxp

Comment: Hmmn, you may find IETester more convenient, as you have limited disk space.  I saw it on the duplicate link.  I've never used it, and I still think that the IE VHDs are the best idea.  http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 0):

http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE

I use this one all the time when I'm testing sites.

> Ever wanted to test your website in various versions of Internet Explorer?
>
> It is possible to run Internet Explorer in standalone mode without having to over-write previous versions thanks to Joe Maddalone who came up with a way of achieving that in November 2003. Basically, Internet Explorer is run by exploiting a known workaround to DLL hell - which was introduced in Windows 2000 and later versions - called DLL redirection.

Comment: but IE 7 doesn't work in Win7 :(