# How do I install IE 7 after having already installed IE 8?

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, downgrade

I would prefer to have 8 & 7 at the same time, but it is not necessary.

The purpose is for web development testing. Not HTML and layout as that is handled through browser mode, but I want to test JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple versions of internet explorer on a machine](http://superuser.com/questions/17670/multiple-versions-of-internet-explorer-on-a-machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this article to have IE6, 7 and IE8 running on Windows Vista, all at the same time!

http://www.vincecutting.co.uk/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-pc-even-on-vista.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have both browsers installed on the same machine, unless you go with a virtual machine.

EDIT:

Or try [IETester](http://kossovsky.net/index.php/2009/06/ietester-multiple-internet-explorer-versions-on-the-same-pc/).