# windows ISO file to use with VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, iso-image

I read [here](https://superuser.com/a/291663/135571) on superuser.com that windows XP ISO files are not generally available for downloads from legitimate sources. What version of Windows can I use then, to mount as an ISO file with VirtualBox? And from where do i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your own image (*.iso) from physical media with any of a number of CD imaging tools. [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) is a popular choice.

Also worth noting that an [MSDN OS Subscription](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/list/parentCategoryID.50804600/categoryID.50804800) from Microsoft lets you download ISOs for pretty much every version of Windows they've ever shipped, including all variants of Windows XP, which are readily usable in VMs.

Comment: for that you need a CD right? I dont have it and that is exactly the reason i asked this...

Comment: @pnp: If you don't have a Windows installation media and license, then you cannot install it legitimately. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @DanielAndersson if you still have a genuine license key you can legitimately install it from not-so-trusted sources. There are unmodified ISOs available, which you can check through the publicly visible checksums for the ISO files.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows Vista SP1](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/w/microsoft_os/3317.2-3-microsoft-windows-vista-official-iso-download-links-digital-river.aspx)
[Windows 7 SP1](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/w/microsoft_os/3316.2-1-microsoft-windows-7-official-iso-download-links-digital-river.aspx)

Those contain official links from Microsoft's distributor DigitalRiver. Note that you'll still need a licence key to activate them, though.

You can also get a 90-day evaluation version of Windows 7 Enterprise from Technet:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495