# Windows XP ISO not booting

Tags: windows-xp, boot, iso-image

Ok, so I know that similar questions to this have been asked many times, but I think my situation is somewhat unique:

I'm trying to re-install Windows XP Pro on 3 older machines (they have OEM copies, so I am using the Product Keys on the stickers on the cases).  I downloaded an .iso of Windows XP Pro 32 bit SP3 direct from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=25129

First, I tried burning an install disc on a CD-RW.  The disc looked good (was not just an .iso file, had autorun and all the other things you would expect).  In one machine, I would get the "Press any key to boot from CD" prompt, but nothing happened.  In the other machine it wasn't even recognized.

Next, I tried burning a DVD.  Again, everything looked good, but the machine still wouldn't recognize it or boot from it.

I tried downloaded Rufus to make a bootable USB (http://rufus.akeo.ie/), but I get the following error: "This version of Rufus only supports bootable ISOs based on bootmgr/WinPE, isolinux or EFI.  This ISO doesn't appear to use either..."

Is this not the correct ISO?  Is the problem that I've tried CD-RWs and DVDs, and should just use a CD-R?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: U receommend the following: 1)Try CDR 2) Try different ISO 3) try USB with [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

Comment: Is there a current OS on the machines you are trying to install? If so, make sure that the CD/DVD you created is readable, for example by the CMD command `xcopy /s {CD drive letter}:\ nul:`

Comment: Are you sure this is the right image? I *think* this is just the service pack, and *not* a full install. If I'm right, it isn't *supposed* to be bootable.

Comment: @AFH - yes, the CD/DVD is readable.

Comment: @Izam - that thought occurred to me too, but I'm not 100% sure how to check.

Comment: You are trying to install 32 or 64bit Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the same mistake.  That file is just the service pack (a collection of patches), not the operating system.  I have been unable to find an iso file anywhere for any version of XP, itself, for several years.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  It's really ridiculous that Microsoft provides Windows 7 ISOs on digital river for anyone to download, but XP ISOs are so difficult to track down!

Comment: and you don't have one from several years ago? it's very unfortunate that there are internet pirates that are able to get these thinsg easily but good citizens that judiciously abide by the law, speed limits, seat belts  e.t.c. are unable to. Do you have a license? if so, then according to one or two  comments here http://superuser.com/questions/291616/where-can-i-download-copies-of-a-windows-xp-iso-image-with-internet-explorer-6-o it looks like downloading a pirate copy may be legal for the downloader if the downloader has a license.That is what i've heard too from a lawyer corroborating them

Comment: I'm not sure that someone offering a pirated copy would be high on my list of safe sources.

Comment: You may want to look at http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/software/1306762/how-to-slipstream-an-xp-disc-with-sp3-and-all-other-updates if you are going make a habit of reinstalling XP. This will create you an install disc with all the patches that have ever been issued.

Comment: Looks like you need an XP install disk to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to burn it as an image!

Simply making it as a "copy" will not extract the image properly.  There are many free software that does this out there. Look for an image burning program.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I made that clear in the post - I am making an image, it is not just a copy.