# Do IE standalone-browser still exist (and run on Win 7?)

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I need to do some IE 9 testing. The last time I did serious IE testing was back when I was running XP and IE6 standalones.

I now have Windows 7 and IE11. Do older IE standalones still exist that will run on Windows 7? Google is failing me on this one (or rather, I'm probably failing Google).

Comment: Microsoft offers free Virtual Machines for the purpose of testing different versions of IE. There isn't a way to have IE9 and IE11 installed.  They offer every possible combination you might image for all 3 major types of VMs ( Hyper-V, VMWare, and VirtualBox ) so there literally isn't a reason not to use them.

Comment: ...other than it's a bigger pain that just installing a browser but...OK, so be it. That'll have to do. :) Any suggestions on which is easiest to set up of the three flavors?

Comment: If you think having to install and reinstall different versions of IE is easier I suggest you go that direction.  To answer your direct question, no, stand alone of IE9+ has not been released for a varity of reasons.

Comment: @Ramhound well, back in the day there were (unofficial) stand-alone portable versions of IE6, 7, and 8, which were pretty nice to have.

Comment: They were unofficial for a reason and they don't exist for the newer versions of IE. There are other [solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-internet-explorer-6-internet-explorer-7-and-internet-explorer-8-on-the) if a VM really isn't an option and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/17670/multiple-versions-of-internet-explorer-on-a-machine)

Answer (score 1):

As Ramhound stated, you can get VM's at no cost from Microsoft.  They are available from the Modern IE [website](http://modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) and they have everything from IE6 on XP to IE11 on Win8.1.

They have these VMs available to run on Mac (VirtualBox, VMWare, Parallels) and Linux (VirtualBox) in addition to Windows (VMWare, VirtualBox, Hyper-V and VirtualPC).

---

EDIT:

A good alternative that I use in my development is [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/).  Requires a subscription, but they handle all the VM stuff for you and you can test some mobile and tablet browsers (stock browsers for Android, iPhone, iPad, & Kindle Fire) as well as the stock desktop group.